# JXBrowser - Array.isArray(exception.getStackTrace()) returning false

Tags: jxbrowser

Shouldn't this return an array? 
Makes it very hard to pass objects to mimic the behavior of the client.

In fact even `window.asObject().setProperty("aaa", new String[]{"bbb"});` would not be a Javascript array. See these examples:

```
execute("aaa.splice != null ? 'a' : 'b'")
execute("Arrays.isArray(aaa) ? : 'a' : 'b'")
```

Works fine in UI4J and Rhino, but now not in JXBrowser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JxBrowser only Java primitive types are converted into the native JavaScript types. For other types the property that you set to a JSObject is mapped to the corresponding Java object and when you invoke a method of the JavaScript object the corresponding method of Java object is actually invoked. There are some limitations for arrays in the current implementation, however, you can get the array size and access its members by indexes:

Java:

```
window.setProperty("arr", new String[]{"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"});
```

JavaScript:

```
var length = window.arr.length();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    console.log(window.arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've to understand that. However, it is problematic if a javascript implementation / api takes an argument that could be an array, and you decide to pass that array from java including using potential java objects. In my case the implementation I had checked if it was an array or a "hashmap" object... if the first then it iterated differently... when using this api method from the java world, such as passing an array from exception.getStackTrace() .. then that fails... 

If they've made it possible to access suing brackets notation, then it should be possible to provide a custom js ...

Comment: ... js array with an own implementation that also passes the isArray() check ... even for array like objectss

Comment: Here is an implementation that does that, with an example:

https://hastebin.com/nolivugopi.js

Attribution to:

https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2292-extending-javascript-arrays-while-keeping-native-bracket-notation-functionality.htm

Comment: To override property length is a different matter though ... since it is protected in Array ... and there is a method with the same name in java ... if one can get rid of the java array not to include length method ... and the array is immutable in the java world at least ... then any add or push in the js world call would simply update the underlying array and length there too. It could even update the underlying array in the javaworld ... if that's even desired ... however, updating in the java world and seeing the length change in js world might be difficult ... not sure how it works now

Comment: ... either since it should be pretty much the same.